# AWS Step Function Map Input from Lambda returning a string array

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a lambda integrated with API gateway (Proxy Integration)

Lambda returns :

```
    collection = [
       {
          "name": "string1"
       },
       {
          "name": "string2"
       } 
     ]

   response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': JSON.stringify(collection)
       }
    return response
```

This works fine because in Proxy Integration **body** needs to be a string. If I dont convert the JSON array into string, API gateway throws 502 gateway error. So I need to convert it into string.

Now, Im planning to use same lambda for AWS Step function where a map needs JSON array as input.

How do I convert this stringify-ed JSON array to normal array for Map to process?

I have tried to use States.StringToJson

**Old:**

[image]

**New:**

[image]

I get invalid JSONPath format error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [States.StringToJson](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) intrinsic function to convert the string to JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I tried using States.StringToJson but it displays it as invalid JSONPath, any suggestions?

Comment: There are specific places where the intrinsic functions can be used. You likely need to get the raw data in one place and use the function in another. For example, in the result path you get the raw data.  Use the result selector to convert it to JSON.

Comment: you are right @Jason, I was able to use StringToJson in ResultSelector and was able to convert, Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Along with Jason answer following documentation helped

https://states-language.net/spec.html#intrinsic-functions

Answer (score 0):

Along with Jason answer following documentation helped

https://states-language.net/spec.html#intrinsic-functions